# How to make async ajax request really async?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I added new feature on my site. Administrator uploading archive with some pictures (rent recepits) and these picture are sending to users. There are 50-100 users on my site atm. Max users is 700-1000.

I am sending email with php `mail()` function. It takes time. It takes ~3.5 seconds to send 1 message via `mail()`. I need to send at least 100 messages.

I had next code structure:

`Main script`:

1. drawing form with input type=file
2. uploading archive with this
   form
3. check name of archive, content of archive. All files must be
   of a certain format
4. Making an ajax request to script
   `send_rent_receipts.php`. Month and year are sending as parameters

`send_rent_receipts.php` (getting month and year):

1. unpack files to directory `.../$year/$month`
2. foreach file in directory `.../$year/$month` do:

   - get name of file (name is like 774.pdf, 772.pff — name of file    connect this file to user
   - get e-mail of user
   - send e-mail with attachement (current file)

This method was working for ~35 seconds with 10 files. ~3.5 seconds with 1 file.

My hosting provider set `max_execution_time 30` in `php.ini` so this script fails (because it is working much more then 30 seconds.

I tried another method:

`main script`:

1. drawing form with input type=file
2. uploading archive with this form
3. check name of archive, content of archive. All files must be of a certain format
4. unpack archive to directory `.../$year/$month`
5. foreach file in directory `.../$year/$month` do

   - get file name
   - make ajax request to script `send_rent_receipts.php` (filename, month, year are sending)

`send_php_script.php`:

1. get user data/e-mail
2. send file `.../$year/$month/$filename` to this
   mail

I thought this method is what I need. Server will make not 1 ajax request, but XX ajax requests (depending on amount of files). Each request will work for 3.5 seconds. Ajax requests are async (I thought. And they must be) so all process (XX ajax requests) will work for 3.5 seconds.

But... What I see? There are 3 images with tests with different amount of files (1, 3, 10 files):

Sending 1 e-mail: 
[image: 1 e-mail]

Sending 3 e-mails:
[image: 3 e-mails]

Sending 10 e-mails:
[image: 10 e-mails]

Why ajax requests (`async: true` as default) are working as not async requests. This images shows, that 10 ajax requests to script which send 1 e-mail takes same time as 1 requests to script which send 10 e-mails.

Why it is so? I thought they must be async and all subscribe will take 3.5 seconds.

How to reduce script execution time? what a way to make it run faster

P.S.: files are not equal, so I can't send 1 e-mail to 10 recepients.

Comment: Just because the browser is making the requests asynchronously doesn't mean the server will handle the requests all at once. Your screenshots show the requests are being sent asynchronously, so you need to clarify what your issue actually is.

Comment: So my question will be: is it possible to run XX same scripts (handle the requests all at once) at 1 moment? Or what approach should be if server can't do this.

Comment: Indeed, it looks like the back-end is the bottleneck. Ajax request should be cheap.

Comment: Okay. Maybe my question is not really correct. Ajax requests really SENDING async-ly, but how to make server handle all these requests at 1 time.

Comment: Is the send_rent_receipt script using session_start() ? If so, this will lock up the script until the session is released.

Comment: @Anthony nope, it isn't. I added `session_start();` at start of the file and got next result: [image](http://i.gyazo.com/96805e89d0dab80c3a665f546c165955.png) Well at least it is looks like true now. Each next request is working for ~ +3.5 seconds to last one. Mhm... Is the time on each row (I mean my last image) means script executing time? Maybe it shows time period between sending request and getting answer? Look's like script is working for ~3.5 seconds (so it will work on my host, because execute time is lesser 60 s.).

Comment: So the problem is solved, right? Can you clarify why it works with `session_start();`? Maybe in answer? You answer helped.

Answer (score 0):

You could send the request asynchroniously, but wait to send the next message before the first one has completed.

The reason why your requests takes longer, when you are doing multiple requests at once, is because every request accesses the disk, which is an atomic operation, so only one request can make the disk operations at a time, so if you are doing multiple requests which are accessing the disk, then the requests that are not handling the disk operations right now, needs to wait for the the one that does.

And you shouldn't use sync ajax requests, because they will block the javascript thread will the request is going on, so if you send a request, wait for the callback and send the next, you will simulate sync request, without blocking the javascript thread, and you won't get request timeouts, because there is only one request at the time accessing the disk, so no requests are waiting for another to be finished with disk work.